# Obtener la instancia de ese objeto después del .save() para hacer un update

Tags: python, django, django-models

He guardado un objeto con `.save()` y me gustaría obtener el id para actualizarlo después de guardarlo, sabéis alguna forma de hacer una consulta sobre la misma instancia generada del objeto.

He probado con el siguiente código pero no me actualiza.

```
dash.save()
Dashboard.objects.filter(pk=dash).update(userInstance=userInstance)
```

Comment: Tal vez un poco más de código de ejemplo y contexto sería útil para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entiendo muy bien lo que estás tratando de hacer. Si quieres actualizar `userInstance` (que asumo es un campo de tu modelo `Dashboard`) solo tienes que usar la instancia que tienes a la mano:

```
dash.userInstance = userInstance
dash.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

una vez que grabas ya puedes manipular los datos de forma directa.

ejemplo:

```
dash.save() #guardas la primera vez

print(dash.id)
dash.name = 'Nuevo nombre'
dash.campo = 'Nuevo valor'
dash.save() #realizas el update
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola es sencillo no hace falta nada, solo accede al atributo id:

```
dash.save()
print(dash.id) # asi de simple
```

Saludos